# Order by ignoring second criteria

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having problems with my query, basically what I'm trying to do here is to order first by

> item_info.content_time desc

and then by

> item_views.views desc

My intention is to get the most recent items (order by item_info.content_time desc), with the most views (item_views.views desc). In essence something like the stackoverflow main page, where you have the most recent with the most views (I really don't know if that's how they are doing it). The following query either orders the items by one criteria or the other (if I reverse the order by criteria). Here's my code:

```
SELECT item_info.item_id, item_info.profile_id, item_info.tittle, item_covers.reference, usuarios.username, item_views.views
FROM item_info
LEFT JOIN item_covers ON item_covers.cover_id = item_info.book_id
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON item_info.profile_id = usuarios.id
LEFT JOIN item_views ON item_views.id = item_info.book_id
WHERE item_info.content_time
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) + INTERVAL -1
DAY )
AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) + INTERVAL 1
DAY ) 
order by item_info.content_time desc, item_views.views desc
```

Roughly something like...

Expected output:

content_time    |      views

17:00                      500 
13:00                      300 
11:00                      100 
10:00                      50

Actual output:

content_time    |      views

17:00                      500 
16:00                      10 
15:00                      30 
14:00                      50

Comment: @RC I don't think they are the same, "A" is content_time and "B" is views, can you expand a bit mote?

Comment: Your "Expected output" can be achieved purely by sorting by `views desc`, and ignoring the time. Are you sure you don't just want some kind of cutoff filter (e.g. a `WHERE` clause that only gives you rows for the last 24 hours)? If not, can you explain how the two separate columns are actually meant to interact to determine a final sort order?

Comment: Can you add `12:00,700` and `19:00,1` to the expected output?

Comment: @RC I don't think so, since "content_time" is a timestamp column (hence the UNIX_TIMESTAMP conversion). I guess I was trying to implement some sort of a filter, without actually having one... Sorry if the question was vague guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a combination of the two you should create a column consisting of the combined (possibly weighed by an extra factor) sum of both like `DATEDIFF(content_time,NOW())+views`. By using DATEDIFF you will make sure that `content_time` is a numeric type and can be added to `views`. By using `DATEDIFF()`with the arguments in the shown order you will be getting a negative number for any `content_time`s in the past which will reduce the combined value with `views` accordingly.

So your query should end in something like this

```
..
...
ORDER BY DATEDIFF(viewsitem_info.content_time,NOW())+viewsitem_info.views desc
```

`DATEDIFF()` gives the difference in days. Maybe you want to be a bit more precise. In that case you might want to use `TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,viewsitem_info.content_time,NOW())` instead.

@Aaron: You will not have to change your data structure at all. If necessary you should introduce some kind of weighing factor like

```
ORDER BY 
(0.123* TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,viewsitem_info.content_time,NOW()) 
      + viewsitem_info.view) DESC
```

Comment: Honestly I think this is the way to go, but I'll have to change my table structure for this to work. I'm not sure about that at this point

Answer (score 0):

write Your query like below

```
SELECT item_info.item_id, item_info.profile_id, item_info.tittle, item_covers.reference,
usuarios.username, item_views.views FROM item_info
LEFT JOIN item_covers ON item_covers.cover_id = item_info.book_id
LEFT JOIN usuarios ON item_info.profile_id = usuarios.id
LEFT JOIN item_views ON item_views.id = item_info.book_id
WHERE item_info.content_time
BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) + INTERVAL -1DAY )
    AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP( CURDATE( ) + INTERVAL 1
 DAY ) 
order by item_info.content_time,item_views.views desc
```

I think it'll work.